# Could not find the module

Tags: node.js, typescript

**db.ts**

```
 const mysql = require('mysql');
     
    const con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'user',
      password: 'password',
    });
    
    con.connect((err) => {
      if(err){
        console.log('Error connecting to Db');
        return;
      }
      console.log('Connection established');
    });
    
    con.end((err) => {
      
    });
    
    
    module.exports =con;
```

**index.ts**

```
import con from "./db"   

con.connect();
```

I created a module called db and and tried imported on index.ts file .Once I run the index.ts file I've got the following error.

```
Cannot find module './db' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Comment: Try `import con from "./db.ts"`. Also check how your `tsconfig.json` is set up.

Comment: Are db and index in the same folder? Your import path is written in that way.

Comment: @TusharShahi      yes both are in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

You use module import you must use this way

```
const con = require('./db');
con.connect();
```

if you want to do same as your code you must change your tsconfig.json

Comment: what should I do to tsconfig.js to import db module"

Comment: "module": "commonjs" use this instead of "module": "es6"